# RevenueCat: Unable to complete purchase due to # of receipts allowed?

Tags: revenuecat

I'm using v4.16.0 and when I try subscribing to auto-renewal purchase I get this error:

> The subscriber has reached the max number of apple receipts allowed.

At the moment the app is already live and this is critical.

I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: You can delete the customer from the dashboard and have them re-subscribe. It's either a test user that has made a bunch of purchases or could be a large group of people sharing the same Apple account. The max receipt limit is in place to protect you from thousands of customers sharing the same login or potential bugs in your app if you set a non-unique App User ID.

Comment: Used test user to subscribe a lot

Comment: Will try to delete customer as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the customer from the dashboard solved the issue. I was able to subscribe again successfully and activate plan in the app.

Thank you @enc_life and @elwatto for your kind support in sensitive time.

I really appreciate it.